# Why does the Installation of Prestashop 1.7 fail on windows?

Tags: node.js, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

**This error can't be reproduced and was only happening on first release.**

---

I'm trying to install Prestashop 1.7 from GitHub develop branch on my Windows 10 Operating system.

I followed those instructions:

> If you installed PrestaShop from GitHub :
>
> - Install Composer (https://getcomposer.org)
> - Install Node.js (https://nodejs.org)
> - Install Grunt-cli globally (http://gruntjs.com)
> - Copy/rename app/config/parameters.yml.dist file to parameters.yml
>
> Then run :
>
> - `composer install`
> - `npm install -g grunt-cli`
> - `npm install`

the first two commands worked fine but `npm install` fails:

```
npm WARN prestashop-common@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN prestashop-common@1.0.0 No license field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.6.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! prestashop-common@1.0.0 install: `npm -C js/vendor install; npm -C admin-dev/themes/default install; npm -C tests/js install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the prestashop-common@1.0.0 install script 'npm -C js/vendor install; npm -C admin-dev/themes/default install; npm -C tests/js install'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the prestashop-common package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm -C js/vendor install; npm -C admin-dev/themes/default install; npm -C tests/js install
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs prestashop-common
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls prestashop-common
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\wamp\www\prestashop-1-7\npm-debug.log
```

Here is `npm-debug.log` file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install' ]
2 info using npm@3.6.0
3 info using node@v5.6.0
4 silly loadCurrentTree Starting
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 silly install normalizeTree
8 silly loadCurrentTree Finishing
9 silly loadIdealTree Starting
10 silly install loadIdealTree
11 silly cloneCurrentTree Starting
12 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
13 silly cloneCurrentTree Finishing
14 silly loadShrinkwrap Starting
15 silly install loadShrinkwrap
16 silly loadShrinkwrap Finishing
17 silly loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree Starting
18 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
19 silly loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree Finishing
20 silly idealTree:prePrune prestashop-common@1.0.0
21 silly loadIdealTree Finishing
22 silly currentTree prestashop-common@1.0.0
23 silly idealTree prestashop-common@1.0.0
24 silly generateActionsToTake Starting
25 silly install generateActionsToTake
26 silly generateActionsToTake Finishing
27 silly diffTrees action count 0
28 silly decomposeActions action count 0
29 silly executeActions Starting
30 silly install executeActions
31 silly doSerial global-install 0
32 silly doParallel fetch 0
33 verbose correctMkdir C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
34 verbose lock using C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-b6a0850f5942bc3a.lock for C:\wamp\www\prestashop-1-7\node_modules\.staging
35 silly doParallel extract 0
36 silly doParallel preinstall 0
37 silly doReverseSerial remove 0
38 silly doSerial move 0
39 silly doSerial finalize 0
40 silly doSerial build 0
41 silly doSerial global-link 0
42 silly doParallel update-linked 0
43 silly doSerial install 0
44 silly doSerial postinstall 0
45 verbose unlock done using C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-b6a0850f5942bc3a.lock for C:\wamp\www\prestashop-1-7\node_modules\.staging
46 silly executeActions Finishing
47 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting
48 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
49 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Starting
50 silly install runTopLevelLifecycles
51 silly preinstall prestashop-common@1.0.0 C:\wamp\www\prestashop-1-7\prestashop-common-cd71d505
52 info lifecycle prestashop-common@1.0.0~preinstall: prestashop-common@1.0.0
53 silly lifecycle prestashop-common@1.0.0~preinstall: no script for preinstall, continuing
54 silly build prestashop-common@1.0.0
55 info linkStuff prestashop-common@1.0.0
56 silly linkStuff prestashop-common@1.0.0 has C:\wamp\www as its parent node_modules
57 verbose linkBins prestashop-common@1.0.0
58 verbose linkMans prestashop-common@1.0.0
59 silly install prestashop-common@1.0.0 C:\wamp\www\prestashop-1-7\prestashop-common-cd71d505
60 info lifecycle prestashop-common@1.0.0~install: prestashop-common@1.0.0
61 verbose lifecycle prestashop-common@1.0.0~install: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
62 verbose lifecycle prestashop-common@1.0.0~install: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\wamp\www\prestashop-1-7\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\CollabNet\Subversion Client;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\SimplePass\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\npm
63 verbose lifecycle prestashop-common@1.0.0~install: CWD: C:\wamp\www\prestashop-1-7
64 silly lifecycle prestashop-common@1.0.0~install: Args: [ '/d /s /c',
64 silly lifecycle   'npm -C js/vendor install; npm -C admin-dev/themes/default install; npm -C tests/js install' ]
65 silly lifecycle prestashop-common@1.0.0~install: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
66 info lifecycle prestashop-common@1.0.0~install: Failed to exec install script
67 warn prestashop-common@1.0.0 No repository field.
68 warn prestashop-common@1.0.0 No license field.
69 verbose stack Error: prestashop-common@1.0.0 install: `npm -C js/vendor install; npm -C admin-dev/themes/default install; npm -C tests/js install`
69 verbose stack Exit status 1
69 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:232:16)
69 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
69 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:185:7)
69 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
69 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
69 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
69 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)
69 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
70 verbose pkgid prestashop-common@1.0.0
71 verbose cwd C:\wamp\www\prestashop-1-7
72 error Windows_NT 10.0.10586
73 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
74 error node v5.6.0
75 error npm  v3.6.0
76 error code ELIFECYCLE
77 error prestashop-common@1.0.0 install: `npm -C js/vendor install; npm -C admin-dev/themes/default install; npm -C tests/js install`
77 error Exit status 1
78 error Failed at the prestashop-common@1.0.0 install script 'npm -C js/vendor install; npm -C admin-dev/themes/default install; npm -C tests/js install'.
78 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
78 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the prestashop-common package,
78 error not with npm itself.
78 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
78 error     npm -C js/vendor install; npm -C admin-dev/themes/default install; npm -C tests/js install
78 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
78 error     npm bugs prestashop-common
78 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
78 error     npm owner ls prestashop-common
78 error There is likely additional logging output above.
79 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Where is the error coming from ? Where should I search in code for this error ? I'm new to node.js so I'm not quit sure how the install process works.

Answer (score -2):

Frankly, I'd just install [XAMPP virtual server for Windows](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) and download ZIP installation of [PrestaShop 1.7.0.0 beta](https://www.prestashop.com/en/developers-versions), much faster...

Comment: Links to potential solutions are always welcome, but please add some details for future visitors in case the link is no longer available.